# Python: Confusion about class variables

Tags: python, class

I am confused why this happens. I'm defining a class `Myclass` for testing.

```
class Myclass:
    l = []
    def method1(self):
        self.l.append("test")

>>>a = Myclass()
>>>a.l
[]
>>>a.method1()
>>>a.l
['test']
>>>b = Myclass()
>>>b.l
['test']
```

Why does this happen? Why isn't a new `empty` list initialized?

Then

```
class Myclass:
    l = "string1"
    def method1(self):
        self.l = "string2"

>>>a = Myclass()
>>>a.l
'string1'

>>>a.method1()
>>>a.l
'string2'

b = Myclass()
>>>b.l
'string1'
```

Why does this happen for `mutable` objects only?

Comment: Because only mutable objects can be changed in-place (or, to put it another way, because only mutable objects are mutable...)

Comment: And if you did `self.l = ['my_new_list']` in the first snippet, that wouldn't have affected the other instance either.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ,where i did that? i just appended to `l`.But it affected the new instance.why ?

Comment: You didn't do that. If you had, it wouldn't have affected it. The duplicate question explains exactly why.